# psql: Preventing Idle Transactions by Default

Tags: postgresql, psql

To prevent idle transactions in psql by default, I thought I should just set an aggressive `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` in my `.psqlrc`.

This works initially, however, when the connection is killed and psql automatically attempts to re-connect, it doesn't re-run the `.psqlrc`, meaning the shell has no longer has this added layer of safety until I re-run the `SET SESSION idle_in_transaction_timeout`. For my purposes, I don't want to have to re-run manually re-run the commands in my `psqlrc` every time a conn is re-built by psql, especially because I might forget.

Is there a way to re-run the `.psqrc` whenever psql attempts to re-establish a connection? Alternatively, is there a way to just completely kill the psql session if the connection is killed, as a forcing function to re-run the `.psqlrc`?

psql version: 14.8

Example:

```bash
psql -h localhost -W -U postgres -d postgres                                                        
SET
psql (14.8 (Homebrew), server 14.6 (Debian 14.6-1.pgdg110+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# SHOW idle_in_transaction_session_timeout;
 idle_in_transaction_session_timeout
-------------------------------------
 2s
(1 row)

postgres=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
postgres=*# SELECT * FROM bla;
FATAL:  terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout
server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Succeeded.
psql (14.8 (Homebrew), server 14.6 (Debian 14.6-1.pgdg110+1))
postgres=# SHOW idle_in_transaction_session_timeout;
 idle_in_transaction_session_timeout
-------------------------------------
 0
(1 row)

postgres=#
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this if the session is interactive.  For non interactive session, I think ON_ERROR_STOP would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the parameter in your connection string, then it will be set during a reconnect:

```
psql 'options=-cidle_in_transaction_session_timeout=2000 host=localhost user=postgres dbname=postgres'
psql (15.3)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

test=# SHOW idle_in_transaction_session_timeout;
 idle_in_transaction_session_timeout 
═════════════════════════════════════
 2s
(1 row)

test=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
test=*# SELECT 42;
FATAL:  terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Succeeded.
test=# SHOW idle_in_transaction_session_timeout;
 idle_in_transaction_session_timeout 
═════════════════════════════════════
 2s
(1 row)
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`PGOPTIONS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html#id-1.7.3.22.3.4.11.1.1) environment variable.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

The psqlrc behavior is a little unintuitive. I wonder if that should be changed (or at least denoted clearly in the docs), especially when [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) seem to imply that connection settings should/can be set using the .psqlrc, "These files can be used to set up the client and/or the server to taste, typically with \set and SET commands."

Comment: Yes, the part of the documentation that says that it is useful for setting up the server is a bit misleading.  The behavior is logical if you understand that `.psqlrc` is run when `psql` starts. Reconnecting with `\c` or after a disconnection is not a restart of `psql`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `postgresql.conf` file on the server to add

```
idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 2s
```

This is documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-IDLE-IN-TRANSACTION-SESSION-TIMEOUT).

You can also do it from [within SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-altersystem.html):

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 2s;
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

This modifies the `postgresql.auto.conf` file which overrides the aforementioned.

---

Having said that, you should probably ensure that any client applications are correctly disposing their transaction and connection objects, so that you don't need to rely on this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! 

In this case, I don't want to modify any server settings. I want my client defaults to be decoupled from my PG instance defaults.

I'm slightly concerned that this might be a bit of a gap in the psql tooling